# I have a query of 5 tables and about 120,000 rows of outputs. How can I display them in the grid for high performance? sqlserver optimize

Tags: performance, visual-studio, sql-server, query, join

I have a query of 5 tables and about 120,000 rows of outputs. How can I display them in the grid for high performance?

microsoft sqlserver
microsoft visual studio

Comment: What you've tried? What high performance means for you? Why would you display so many rows?...

Comment: I put the results straight into the grid view. I do not know the solution for Paging.